# Why I added g++ to PATH but failed compiling C++ code in atom?

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I am a new C++ developer and I recently installed the Atom editor due to recommendations. I used Code::blocks before, but it happened to have no debuggers. I installed the [gpp-compiler](https://atom.io/packages/gpp-compiler) extension. I also installed MinGW via the installation manager and added it to PATH. I opened Atom and right-clicked on the file I desired to execute, then clicked on the "Compile and run" option presented on the panel that popped out. Below is a screenshot:
[Click here to view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BfYt.png)

After clicking on the option, I discovered that an error popped out (also shown in the screenshot above) that roughly says my g++ isn't installed in PATH. I viewed some websites that displayed the method of how to check MinGW's existence in PATH. The website showed the following method:

1. Open command line interface.
2. Type `g++`.

Screenshot of the result is shown below.

[Click here to view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh7rx.png)

The above process essentially shows success.

However, the error still pops out.

Can anyone tell me why is that?

1. Is MinGW the same as G++?
2. Is my installation process wrong (I installed the packages manager on mingw.org)?

Comment: Question 1. Is MinGW the same as G++?

Comment: Question 2. What is my bug?

Comment: Question 3. Is my installation process wrong?

Comment: Please don't post important information in the comment section but [edit] your question so everyone can find it easy.

Comment: [For question 3. I installed MinGW in MinGW.org.

Comment: _"I used Code::blocks before, but it happened to have no debuggers."_
 http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Debugging_with_Code::Blocks

Comment: _"Is MinGW the same as G++?"_ No, MinGW is a minimal Linux-like system for Windows. G++ is a compiler that can be installed in MinGW.

Comment: Did you reboot your computer to make changes to your path environment variable take effect?

Comment: _"Is my installation process wrong"_ Obviously it's wrong because it doesn't work. But it's difficult to remotely analyze this problem. Editors like Atom, VSCode and Sublime Text are not recommended for beginners. It can be difficult to configure them. You should use a preconfigured IDE like Visual Studio, CLion, Eclipse CDT, Cevelop.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I beg to differ. I think what you talk about is *MSYS*, a Linux shell like environment for Windows, which is pretty much always delivered with MinGW. The actual MinGW is a Windows version of GCC. GCC is a collection of compilers, including (but not limited to) G++ (for instance, GCC also has compilers for C and Fortran).

Comment: @CliffChiang Risking being off topic and opinion based, I recommend that you get QtCreator as IDE. My reason is that the installer comes with everything, including the Qt library and of course a compiler, and also because it uses QMake project files, which I find to be comparatively easy to understand. But in any case, like ThomasSablik already said, get yourself *some* IDE. A lot of beginners use a text editor, but IDEs offer so much tools, quick refactoring and debuggers for instance. Also, no chance to organize a big project made of hundreds of files without one.

Comment: @Aziuth From the website _"MinGW, a contraction of "Minimalist GNU for Windows", is a minimalist development environment for native Microsoft Windows applications."_ GNU development environment is much more than just the compiler. It's a system of tools. GCC resp. G++ is just the compiler. E.g. MinGW contains Make. Make is not part of GCC